# Open cmd, change directory and execute command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to write a simple batch file to initialize some tools I need on windows startup.
This is what I've at the moment:

```
@echo off
start /d "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3" sublime_text.exe
start cmd.exe /k cd /d "D:xampp/htdocs/webshop"
```

What I'd like to do is to execute the command `compass watch` once the directory has changed.

I tried `start cmd.exe /k cd /d "D:xampp/htdocs/webshop" /k "compass watch"` but it refers to the cd command then and thus throws me an error message (The system cannot find the path specified).

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

To clarify what I need:

1. Open console
2. `cd` to the relevant directory
3. Execute the command `compass watch` (in that directory)

I normally do this by manually typing in the commands into the console as listed above. What I'd like to have is a simple .bat file that does exactly that with just one click.

Comment: I cannot work out how to escape the quotes and deal with the spaces. Why do you need "cmd.exe /k"? Can't you do it all in the original interpreter instance?

Comment: If it's possible with the initial interpreter instance that's fine. I've tried it but it immediately closes and the compass watch command needs to run all the time, not just once.

Comment: What is this compass watch? Console app? GUI app?

Comment: http://compass-style.org/ It's a ruby gem. It compiles Sass to CSS on run-time and therefore needs to run all the time...

Comment: If it is a GUI app, then closing the console won't kill it. If it is a console app, then it should run forever, and the cmd script never return. So I don't understand what the problem is. Does the original process launch a separate process?

Comment: It's a console app BUT the command `compass watch` doesn't get executed. I normally simply open manually the console, cd to the relevant path and the type compass watch. But I'd like to have that with one simple click.

Comment: Well, the code in the question has the wrong syntax so it won't work at all. But if you don't need a separate cmd interpreter then you just use another `start /d`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You state in the comments that you don't need a separate interpreter. In which case I believe you can do it like this:

```
@echo off
start /d "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3" sublime_text.exe
start /d D:\xampp\htdocs\webshop compass watch
```

Comment: This does correctly open the console and change the directory but the command `compass watch`doesn't appear/get executed...

Comment: Well, that's going to be hard for me to debug. That must be an issue with your system.

Comment: Without the double quotes it's working! `start /d D:\xampp\htdocs\webshop compass watch` Can you update your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Done. Although I don't really understand why it works like that. Quoting in cmd is a nightmare! I wonder. Is compass the gem, and watch an argument?

Comment: Yes. That appears to be it.

Answer (score 0):

This an example to open Firefox.exe.So you should do like this, for your programs

```
@echo off
echo Try to open Firefox ....
CD /D %programfiles%\Mozilla Firefox\ & Start Firefox.exe
Pause
```

Try This :

```
@echo off
CD /D %programfiles%\Sublime Text 3 & Start sublime_text.exe
CD /D D:\xampp/htdocs/webshop & Start compass watch
Pause
```

Comment: I'm able to open a program but what I need is to execute a command inside of the command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Backslash in your path "\".
Did you try :

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"
cd /d "D:\xampp\htdocs\webshop"
"D:\xampp\htdocs\webshop\compass watch.exe"
```

Comment: As far as I know it's irrelevant whether to use backslashes or not. And compass watch isn't and executable file but a command.

Answer (score 0):

This should work to launch the exe, and change folder, then use cmd /k to execute the compass command and leave the console open.

```
@echo off
start "" /d "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3" sublime_text.exe
cd /d "D:xampp/htdocs/webshop"
cmd.exe /k "compass watch"
```